# prevent re render in child component in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a counter app. I need to prevent re-render component. I want to execute `Childcompnent` only when I clicking on update, but here it is executing both time when I click count or update.

```
import { useCallback, useMemo, useState } from "react";

export const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [updatecount, setUpdateCount] = useState(0);

  const incCount = () => {
    setCount(parseInt(count) + 1);
  };

  const updCount = useCallback(() => {
    return setUpdateCount(parseInt(updatecount) + 1);
  }, [updatecount]);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={incCount}>count</button>
      <button onClick={updCount}>update</button>
      <Childcompnent count={count} />
      <p>{updatecount}</p>
    </>
  );

};

export default App;

export function Childcompnent({ count }) {
  console.log("pressed");
  return <p>{count}</p>;
}
```

Comment: You're not using `ChildComponent` in your parent component. Why don't you want it to re-render? [Here's some documentation on how to create a React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002). Perhaps you could update your question using those steps.

Comment: Why would you not want to re-render? Please clarify and make sure this isn't an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: means i want to execute childcomponent only when i clicking on update , but here it is executing both time when i click count,update

Comment: Apologies to the user who edited the question and who I called out. I hadn't realised that the `<pre>` tags were screwing up the formatting. Your edit was fine.

Comment: @Andy how do you know its `<pre>`?

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly check the post edits. There was a `<pre>` tag surrounding the explanatory text and the code which was screwing up the formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your `Childcompnent` in `React.memo`:

```
const Childcompnent = React.memo(({ count }) => {
  console.log("pressed");
  return <p>{count}</p>;
});
```

Here is the sandbox:

[image: Edit serverless-wood-ro6iek]

Comment: Yeah i got the solution . is any other means can i get the same output by using useCallback method?

Comment: No. `React.memo` is used to wrap React Function components to prevent unnecessary  re-renderings. The `useCallback` is used to memoize functions.